# Jquery get value of select form item

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Right, so I have multiple forms like this on a page (EDIT, since it isn't clear that this is being used in PHP I've added in the PHP and echo tags):

```
 <?PHP
 echo "<form action="" method="post" id="form$field2">";
 echo "<select id="popup" name="state" >";
 echo "<option class="apple-hidden" value="$statitem1">$statitem1</option>";
 echo "<option class="apple-hidden" value="$statitem2">$statitem2</option>";
 echo "<option class="apple-hidden" value="$statitem3">$statitem3</option>";
 echo "<option class="apple-hidden" value="$statitem4">$statitem4</option>";
 echo "<option class="apple-hidden" value="$statitem5">$statitem5</option>";
 echo "<option class="apple-hidden" value="$statitem6">$statitem6</option>";
 echo "<option class="apple-hidden" value="$statitem7">$statitem7</option>";
 echo "<option class="apple-hidden" value="$statitem8">$statitem8</option>";
 echo "<option class="apple-hidden" value="$statitem9">$statitem9</option>";
 echo "</select>";
 echo "<input type="hidden" name="bnum" value="$field2,$user">";
 echo "</form>";
 ?>
```

and I have some javascript so that whenever the form is changed it submits the POST data with AJAX and turns the table cell the form is contained in green.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bnum;
    bnum = '$formname',

    $('form').change(function() {
        console.log(bnum);      

        $.ajax("http://myApp.example.org/alert?title=Test%20from%20AJAX&message=this%20is%20a%20message%20from%20an%20AJAX%20request");
        $(this).closest("td").css("background", "#01DF01");

        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'post',
            url: 'process.php?item1=$urlvar3',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {
            }
        });
        return false;
    });  
</script>
```

Now what I want to do is get the new value of the drop down list and print it to the console. I tried:

```
 console.log($("#popup").val());
```

which works, but only for the first form on the page. What I want to be able to do is to get data out of the form that I'm submitting, so I tried:

```
 console.log($(this).val());
```

but this returns NULL.

Any help is as always appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the same `id` attribute multiple times. Can you confirm this? Do you have multiple elements with the id `popup`?

Comment: ID's should be unique, else it will return the first result only. If you have multiple forms the same, it means you are using the `popup` ID more than once. You need to make this unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log($(this).find("#popup").val());
```

Comment: The HTML is still invalid. The same ID should not be repeated. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id

Answer (score 0):

TRY to replace

```
$('form').change(function()
```

with

```
$('#popup').change(function()
```

Comment: All of the forms are echo'ed in PHP. I just excluded the PHP and echo tags. The forms items do actually have values.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` should be unique in the document.

Better accessor would be

```
$('#popup',this)
```

or without duplicate `id` (and assuming only one select)

```
$('select',this)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the same ID multiple times on your page, which is invalid. IDs should be unique. Instead, just get rid of the ID attribute altogether and search for it by name:

```
console.log($(this).find('select[name="popup"]').val());
```